# Vertex color to Texture (Smart UV) PC freeze

Tags: uv, texture-baking, polycount

So I'm pretty new to Blender. What I'm trying to do is convert a face scan from iphone app ScandyPro from vertex colors to a texture (in .ply file).

I'm following two tutorials: [Scandy Pro 3D Mesh Scan to Generate Texture Map](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOxTXN-IjaI) and [Easily Clean Your 3D Scans](https://youtu.be/dKo0rWXVAlc?t=96), where they bake the texture.

The problem is, I don't have the best PC (Radeon RX 470 , not supported for cycles) and probably because of too many polygons, my PC freezes and never finishes the smart uv process.

I have tried applying *Decimate modifier*, with ratio 0.1 with noticeable quality reduction, but still not luck.

Is there any way I can ease the smart uv process, so it finishes and doesn't freeze?

Thank you

Comment: Can you describe what you did? You scanned an object (=high poly) ... and then? Have you tried to UV unwrap it? Or have you used *Instant Meshes* first as described in the 2nd video link? (UV unwrapping a high-poly object is a bad idea)

Comment: Sorry I can't explain myself properly. Yes I scanned the object, used _Instant Meshes_ to make a low poly version, and now I want to apply the texture from high poly to low poly version (because _Instant Meshes_ does not calculate UV or textures). Update: I have just noticed [the second video at 2:15](https://youtu.be/dKo0rWXVAlc?t=135) somehow already has the high poly texture and only bakes it onto the low poly, the video doesn't explain how to get that high poly texture.